# Generate income in Odd number MLM

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate income in odd numbers in MLM.

If left = 2 and right = 3 then it should generate income...

but current code is, if left = 4 and right = 1 then it is generating income...

```
$gettotalleft  = $class_database->getdata("paidleft", "id='$useridp'", "user"); 
$gettotalright = $class_database->getdata("paidright", "id='$useridp'", "user");    
$mincome=$gettotalleft+$gettotalright;  //Total LEft Right Child-----


if($mincome == 5){
    $incm=250;
    $TDate= date('Y-m-d');
    $ntp =$nsdp['Type'];
    $sql=mysqli_query($sql_conn,"insert into payment values('0','$useridp','$incm','Matching','','paid','','','','N/A','$TDate','$ntps')");
    if($sql){
        $ddhg =mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($sql_conn,"select * from balance where userid='$useridp'"));
        $nbld =$ddhg['balance']+$incm;
        echo $nbld;
        mysqli_query($sql_conn,"update balance set balance='$nbld' where userid='$useridp'");
        }else{ 
            echo "not updated";
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: I am storing left and right value into variable..as `$gettotalleft` and `$gettotalright`

Comment: What is MLM? what is left and right?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @Rizki Hadiaturrasyid  MLM is Multi level Marketing.. and people join left and right in binary plan...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if $gettotalleft is equal 2 and $gettotalright is equal 3, you just need:

```
if($gettotalleft == 2 and $gettotalright == 3){
//do something
}
```

If this is not what you want, you need to be a lot more specific when explaining your question.